# Identify the files opened a particular process on linux

Tags: linux, process, pid

I need a script to identify the files opened a particular process on linux

To identify fd :

```
>cd /proc/<PID>/fd; ls |wc –l
```

I expect to see a list of numbers which is the list of files descriptors' number using in the process. Please show me how to see all the files using in that process. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

The command you probably want to use is `lsof`.  This is a better idea than digging in `/proc`, since the command is a more clear and a more stable way to get system information.

```
lsof -p pid
```

However, if you're interested in `/proc` stuff, you may notice that files `/proc/<pid>/fd/x` is a symlink to the file it's associated with.  You can read the symlink value with `readlink` command.  For example, this shows the terminal stdin is bound to:

```
$ readlink /proc/self/fd/0
/dev/pts/43
```

or, to get all files for some process,

```
ls /proc/<pid>/fd/* | xargs -L 1 readlink
```

Answer (score 9):

While lsof is nice you can just do:

```
ls -l /proc/pidoftheproces/fd
```

Answer (score 6):

```
lsof -p <pid number here> | wc -l
```

if you don't have lsof, you can do roughly the same using just `/proc`

eg

```
$ pid=1825
$ ls -1 /proc/$pid/fd/*
$ awk '!/\[/&&$6{_[$6]++}END{for(i in _)print i}' /proc/$pid/maps
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof). To get the PID of the application which opened foo.txt:

```
lsof | grep foo.txt | awk -F\  '{print $2}'
```

or what Macmede said to do the opposite (list files opened by a process).

Comment: That will list the processes using a file. I think he wants the files used by a process... So type the process name instead of the file name...

Answer (score 1):

```
lsof | grep processName
```