# Linux: get list of files a program currently has open

Tags: linux

In Linux, how can I get a list of files currently open in program X?

(Specifically, I'm on Fedora, and the program is Zend Studio, but I assume there's a general answer.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681501/identify-the-files-opened-a-particular-process-on-linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify the files opened a particular process on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681501/identify-the-files-opened-a-particular-process-on-linux)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use e.g. `lsof` ("list open files") and filter the output, or use the `-c programX` option to restrict it to files opened by programX.  This expression can be a wildcard.

Comment: I've tried `lsof | grep somefile`, where `somefile` is a file I know is open in Zend Studio, but it finds nothing. Same thing if a file is open in gedit. Maybe these files aren't technically "open" except for when the program is actively reading or saving them, and the rest of the time it just has a copy in memory and a reference to where the file is stored?

Answer (score 6):

You can find symbolic links to the actual files in `/proc/PID/fd` where `PID` is the process ID.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm trying to determine the process ID - I did `ps -AF | grep zend` and got various listings (I have Zend Server running, etc), but nothing that looked like studio. I closed Zend Studio and tried again, and the list was the same. Any thoughts on how to determine the PID, other than "start killing them and see when it closes?"

Answer (score 2):

`ls -l /proc/<zend studio's pid>/fd` will print a list of file descriptors. Those that map to files that were opened through `open()` will be symlinks to the file path used to open them.

Answer (score 1):

Install the program `lsof` if you haven't already.  Get the pid of the running program.  Run `lsof -p [pid]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
lsof -p [PID]
```

Or, to get the PID in one go

```
lsof -p `pgrep [PROG_NAME]`
```

Or, even simpler

```
lsof -c [PROG_NAME]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ls /proc/PID/fd | wc -l
```

Which retuns the count of files opened by PID
or you can use lsof(list of open files)

```
lsof -a -p pid
```